# Elastic Response modifier Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

is it possible implement plugin modify search response from elastic?

In Solr we can extend SearchHandler to modify response from solr.

**use case** - calling external service find authorization and return authorized data in response. Intercept query response and call external service and find authorized and return those authorized in response.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a new `FetchSubPhase` by a custom search plugin :

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/b84a6ed5e6fc1e057f8c0f4d6758a80b3d2a51fd/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugins/SearchPlugin.java#L84

However, to make outbound calls - you will need to modify jvm security policy.

Comment: how to register this plugin? can i simply override searchplugin and register as RestAction type?